# MvvmLight : How to unsubscribe "RaisePropertychanged" Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light

I have a problem in my WPF application with MvvmLight.

**My application :**

- I have a MainView with a menu, each MenuItem will open a new view (different for each menuitem).
- Each MenuItem is bound to a RelayCommand of my MainViewModel
- In my MainViewModel, the RelayCommand just do `Messenger.Default.Send(this, "ShowMyView")` to the MainView.
- In my MainView, I'm registered on the message "ShowMyView" and actions are :

`var v = new MyView();
v.Owner = this;
v.ShowDialog();
Messenger.Default.Unregister(v);`

This new view (MyView) is bound on a viewmodel (MyViewModel) that contains properties. 
Elements of this view (textbox, radiobutton, etc) are bound to these properties.

When I close "MyView", It's disposed and I come back to my mainview but the "MyViewModel" still exist.

**Problem :**

When I first open "MyView", binding works properly, if "MyViewModel" set a property, the RaisePropertyChanged is called, then the "get" of this property is call once.

But If I open and close my view 20 times, at the 20th times, when a RaisePropertyChanged is called, the get of this property is call 20 times !

**Question :**

So how can I unsubscribe these "RaisePropertyChanged" when I close a view ?

Hopping it's clear for you, and sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT : With code**

**EDIT BIS**

Instead of putting some part of code, please found on my github a complete project where the problem occured.

https://github.com/damgot/MvvmLightProblemExample

When I run the application, the MainWindow start :

[image]

You can see in Debug Output :

```
Starting
Creating NewViewModel
```

Then, when I click on NewView Menu, the newview open :

[image]

And you can see in Debug output :

```
Initialize NewViewModel and set MyBool to true
MyBool Set call + RaiseProperty
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
```

Seems Ok as I have 2 radio button bound on "MyBool"

Now if I select the "MyBool is false" Radio button :

[image]

and in output :

```
MyBool Set call + RaiseProperty
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
```

Still good.

Now, If I close the NewView, and open it again, and select "MyBool is false" Radio button, the output is :

```
MyBool Set call + RaiseProperty
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
```

Then once again, output is  :

```
MyBool Set call + RaiseProperty
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
```

and once again :

```
MyBool Set call + RaiseProperty
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
MyBool Get call
```

And so on...

As You can see, "Get" call on my property, increase each team I re-open the view

Comment: Please share a code example of your issue.

Comment: What if you set the `v.Owner = null` after the `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Which version of mvvmlight are you using and what framework does your solution target? Your command using statement, Does that have WPF on the end, or not?

Comment: I've add some code.
I use nuget package "MvvmLightLibs v5.3.0" and the application target .NET Framework 4.5.2. Yes it's a WPF application

Comment: Instead of using viewmodellocator. Try making MyViewModel a private member of myview,. Instantiate it in xaml. Does your problem go away?

Comment: Change v.Owner = null doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I don't think it's retaining a reference to the view is your issue. As above.

Comment: @Andy : Thanks for your answer. Yes, if I don't use viewmodellocator but create the viewModel in the MyView.xaml.cs it works. But all my app is based on viewmodellocator (I currently have 29 differents views) and share an applicationcontext to all viewmodel. Is there another solution ?

Comment: Service locator is a bad idea imo. Google "service locator is an anti pattern".  You could make the viewmodel a singleton. If all you're really doing with your ioc is injecting one object then you could make that a static instead.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for your help. Unfortunattely I'm not alone on this project, and abandon the viewmodellocator will be the very last solution.
I've just edit my question, and I've put an example project on GitHub, you can download it and test it if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution, a prettier one than the first solution I've posted.

In my ViewModelLocator, I've removed every viewmodel properties.
And I've create this static function instead :

```
public static T GetViewModelInstance<T>(Window w)
{
    var uniqueKey = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    T VMInstance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>(uniqueKey);
    w.Closed += (sender, args) => SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister(uniqueKey);
    return VMInstance;
}
```

So, as you can see, I do not return the ViewModel but a new instance of it (with the uniqueKey Token).
And I'm registered on the calling view Closed event to unregister the created VM instance.

I no longer define the DataContext in the xaml but xaml.cs, in the constructor, I set the DataContext as follow :

```
DataContext = ViewModelLocator.GetViewModelInstance<NewViewModel>(this);
```

And It works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but it's an ugly one.

As I said in comment, I'm not alone in my project, and the solution involved other project that I can not edit. So I can not simply suppress the "ViewModelLocator".

So to fix my problem, in my ViewModelLocator, in my ViewModels properties, instead of doing this :

```
public NewViewModel NewView
{
    get
    {
        var vm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NewViewModel>();
        vm.Initialize();
        return vm;
    }
}
```

I do this :

```
public NewViewModel NewView
{
    get
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<NewViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<NewViewModel>(true);
        var vm = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<NewViewModel>();
        vm.Initialize();
        return vm;
    }
}
```

Each time I call a ViewModel (so when I open a view), the model is Unregistered then Registered. It force to recreate a ViewModel, so all subscriptions to PropertyChanged are reset.

I will not set this solution as the good one because I think this solution is not very pretty. But it works and the used memory seems not raising.